OidcUserService loadbyUser not beign triggered How do i fix it?
@Service
public class CustomOAuth2UserService  extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);

@Override
public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    logger.info("CustomOAuth2UserService triggered");
    DefaultOAuth2UserService delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
    OAuth2User oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
    Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes();
    String username = (String) attributes.get("preferred_username");

    Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    User user = new User(username, "", authorities);

    return new DefaultOAuth2User(authorities, (Map<String, Object>) user, "username");
}

public String getOAuth2Email(Map<String, Object> attributes) {

    return (String) attributes.get(StandardClaimNames.EMAIL);
}

}




@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    JWTService jwtService = new JWTServiceImpl();

    http
            .cors()
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository())
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/saml/**")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("*/oauth2/**")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/login")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/extraction/**")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/trialRegister")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/user/trialSignUp")
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/ai-ml/savePerformanceMetricAndPrediction");

    http
            .headers().contentTypeOptions()
            .and().frameOptions().deny();

    http
            .headers().contentSecurityPolicy("frame-ancestors 'none'");

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                    "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/pre-auth").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/sso/login").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
            .and().successHandler(customSuccessHandler());

//        http
//                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
//                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
//                                .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
//              )
//          );

    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home");

    http
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtService,    userDetailsService, expirationTime, cacheService, isConcurrentLoginAllowed))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtService, cacheService, isConcurrentLoginAllowed))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

    return http.build();
}

I am trying to implement SSO using azure and have my frontend in angular and spring boot . Above are my Config and customOidcUser classes I am trying to call the customOAuth2UserService in but it is not being triggered . I have securityfilter chain implemented as above. I have a JWTAuthentication and JWTAuthorization implemented along with custom code. Major problem I am now facing is that customOAuth2UserService is not triggered . Can anyone help me with this
